# How to add mailchimp integration script to next.js `Head` without creating pre-render errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, mailchimp

Heyo

I'm trying to add mailchimp integration to my nextjs site and I can't seem to do it by adding the following to `next/Head` in my custom `_document`

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/6de8d2d6c939d766316a64859/bd399ce06369bd3a09a174bb7.js");</script>
```

I think the problem has something to do with the script tag being a `!function`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

The Error I get is

```
remote: Error occurred prerendering page
remote: ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

Comment: So I'm still stuck on this... Am I suppose to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 9):

My solution is the use `next/head` in custom `_document.js` with dangerouslysetinnerhtml

EG:

```
                <script
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/6de8d2d6c939d766316a64859/bd399ce06369bd3a09a174bb7.js");`,
                        }}
                    />
```

Hope this helps someone :D

Comment: Thank you! You might also want to add `type="text/javascript"` to the script